# Vavr property testing

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, vavr

Property checking feature is advertised in the latest [Vavr documentation](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_stream) along with the following example of its usage:

```
Arbitrary<Integer> ints = Arbitrary.integer();

// square(int) >= 0: OK, passed 1000 tests.
Property.def("square(int) >= 0")
        .forAll(ints)
        .suchThat(i -> i * i >= 0)
        .check()
        .assertIsSatisfied();
```

However, as per the library's [javadoc](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2), neither `Arbitrary` generator nor `Property` type exist.

What am I missing, if any?  Is the documentation up to date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the following **vavr-test** dependency was missing, which is not obvious from Vavr documentation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
    <artifactId>vavr-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr-docs/issues/39)