# Stream generator method in vavr

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, vavr

There's a following example in [Vavr documentation](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs):

```
// 1000 random numbers
for (double random : Stream.gen(Math::random).take(1000)) {
    ...
}
```

However, I cannot find the above method (gen) on Stream type in [vavr javadoc](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2).

These seem to be similar behariors:

```
        for (double nonRandom : Stream.range(1, 20)) {
            System.out.println(nonRandom);
        }

        for (double random : Stream.continually(Math::random).take(7)) {
            System.out.println(random);
        }
```

but is there a `Stream.gen()` somewhere as well?

Am I searching in the wrong places or is it an out-of-date method mentioned in the vavr user guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, vavr documentation is outdated in that regard, as that method got renamed to [`Stream.continually(...)`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/collection/Stream.html#continually-java.util.function.Supplier-) in [pull request 1148](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/pull/1148) to align with the Scala API.

Comment: See also [issue 37](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr-docs/issues/37) where you can track this documentation issue.

Comment: Ah, perfect.  Thanks for the quick fix.  See this for another improvement that could be made to the current usage doc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629111/vavr-property-testing